# What is the term for groups of numerals within a large number?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, numbers, hypernyms

I am writing software in which I would like to be able to return the groups of numerals within a large number. For example, given a number *123,456,789*, my software would return *123* then *456* then *789*.

I would like to give each of the 3-digit sequences a proper name, but I cannot find what the correct one would be. Would it be *groups*? I thought about *thousands*, but that seems imprecise.

I should clarify that I know what to call each individual group (*thousands*, *millions*, etc.). What I don’t know if there is a general term that applies to all the groups.

Comment: You might want to edit the "software" references. The FAQ says that EL&U considers "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" to be off-topic. However, writing documentation for your software would probably be on-topic.

Comment: You could call them *clusters*.

Comment: The standard answer is that you can call a method anything you like, even "Charles()". This is why naming is off-topic. However, the word *group* seems clear enough in the question.

Comment: I suspect that you checked less than the best reply as an answer. The one I'm talking about has images...   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a generic term for subsets of 3 digits so if there is no specific, technical jargon for the collection of three digits within a larger number, then you might want to create/enlist/repurpose a term like "triplet" which communicates the sense of the three nature.

Comment: After spending far too much time trying to find a definitive answer, I'm accepting yours. For the curious, I decided on the term _NamingGroup_.

Comment: One slight weakness with "triplet" is that not all cultures group numbers into threes .  If a program uses methods that format numbers according to the current culture, they may get grouped some other way.  On the other hand, it's possible that the languages associated with such cultures have terms for such groupings, so if the documentation is translated, the translator could replace "triplets" with the appropriate term in the target language.

Answer (score 10):

The precise term for such a group of three digits is a ***period***. Thus you have the *ones period*, the *thousands period*, the *millions period*, etc. This is one of those wonderful terms we all learned (and then forgot) in primary school.

[image: “period” vocabulary card from McGraw-Hill MyMath]

The term is in current use but hard to find in general purpose dictionaries. Here are some modern examples of the term defined in online arithmetic textbooks and study aids:

- “**Commas are used to separate each group of three digits, which is called a period.**” – “[Numbers – Place Value – In Depth](http://math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U1L1DP.html)” at *Math.com*
- “**Period […] The name given to each group of three digits in a place-value chart.**” – “[My Vocabulary Cards](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515050318/https://www.mheonline.com/mhmymath/pdf/G4_Building_language.pdf)”<sup>[PDF]</sup> at *McGraw-Hill MyMath* (source of the image above)
- “**A period is each group of three digits separated by commas in a multidigit number.**” – “[period](http://mathgoodies.com/glossary/term.asp?term=period)” glossary entry at *Math Goodies*

Note that the term is not of modern origin. The word *period* has carried this meaning for hundreds of years. Here is the relevant sense of *period* from *NED* (the predecessor of the *OED*, now public domain):

- “**Period […] A set of figures in a large number marked off by commas placed between or dots placed over.**”

## Full *NED* entry

Here is the full *NED* entry for this sense of the word:

> **Period** (pīᵊ·riŏd), *sb.* Forms: 5 *peryod*, *paryode*, 6 *peryode*, *periode*, 6– *period*: see also P<sub><sup>ARODY</sup></sub> *sb.*² [a.F. *période* (14th c. in Hatz.-Darm.) = Sp. *periodo*, It. *periodo*, ad.L. *period-us*, a.Gr. *περίοδος* going round, way round, circuit, revolution, cycle of years, periodic recurrence, course, recurring fit of disease, orbit of a heavenly body, rounded sentence, f. *περί* around + *ὁδός* way; in ancient L. used only of the period or cycle of the four Grecian games, and of a complete sentence; in med.L. in other of the Gr. senses.]
>     **III.** In Grammar, Rhetoric, Music, etc.
>    **13.** *Arith.* A set of figures in a large number marked off by commas placed between or dots placed over, as in numeration, circulating decimals, and the extraction of the square or cube root.
>    **1674** J<sub><sup>EAKE</sup></sub> *Arith.* (1696) 15 A Period is a comprehension of Degrees .. as 123 .. 12345, &c.
>    *a* **1677** *Cocker’s Arith.* i. § 10. 6 A Period .. when a Number consists of more than three figures or places, whose proper order is to prick or distinguish every third Place .. so .. 63.452.
>    **1690** L<sub><sup>EYBOURN</sup></sub> *Curs. Math.* 4 Numbers .. of Three Figures, or Places .. may properly be called a Period.
>    **1704** J. H<sub><sup>ARRIS</sup></sub> *Lex. Techn.* I. s. v., A Period in Numbers, is a Distinction made by a Point, or Comma after every sixth Place or Figure; and is used in Numeration, for the readier distinguishing and naming the several Figures or Places.
>    **1859** B<sub><sup>ARN</sup></sub>. S<sub><sup>MITH</sup></sub> *Arith. & Algebra* (ed. 6) 76 The part [of a circulating decimal] which is repeated is called the Period.
>    —*A New English Dictionary On Historical Principles (1888)*[¹](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdic07murruoft#page/698/mode/2up)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping refers to the comma or period that separates each set of numbers as a *digit group separator*, so it seems fair to call the groups themselves *digit groups*.

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to digit groups as *[segments](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segment#Noun)*, meaning a contiguous part of something.  Terms like  *[metamere](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/metamere)* (“one of the similar body segments into which earthworms, crayfish, and similar animals are divided longitudinally”) and *[somite](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/somite)* may also be used, somewhat figuratively.  These two terms imply similarity of segments.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find a precise technical term for the group--not quite so figurative.

Answer (score 0):

"Digit group" is used in discussions of software that formats numbers to match users' expectations.

ICU (International Components for Unicode) uses "grouping separator" to refer to a symbol that separates groups (`,` or `.` in most parts of the world) and "grouping sizes" for the numbers of digits in groups.

From [DecimalFormat](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#details):

> The grouping separator is a character that separates clusters of integer digits to make large numbers more legible. It commonly used for thousands, but in some locales it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is the number of digits between the grouping separators, such as 3 for "100,000,000" or 4 for "1 0000 0000". There are actually two different grouping sizes: One used for the least significant integer digits, the primary grouping size, and one used for all others, the secondary grouping size. In most locales these are the same, but sometimes they are different. For example, if the primary grouping interval is 3, and the secondary is 2, then this corresponds to the pattern "#,##,##0", and the number 123456789 is formatted as "12,34,56,789".

Answer (score -1):

*Thousands* would be a good name for the middle (456) group. Similarly, *millions* for the first (123) group; *ones* for the 789 group.

When you speak the number, you would say "One hundred twenty-three million, four hundred fifty-six thousand, seven hundred eighty-nine." The "millions" and "thousands" correspond well to the spoken number, and the "ones" goes without saying.

UPDATE
OK, I see that you're looking for the group name.

I don't see a consensus on this, but here are some of the possibilities:

- *Class* (of ones, of thousands) at http://www.themathpage.com/arith/powers-of-10.htm
- (Ones, Thousands) *Family* at a site for teaching children math, http://greatmathsgames.com/place-value/item/36-place-value-charts.html
- *Group of three numbers* at https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_large_numbers

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in the question. I know what to name each group individually. What I am looking for is a general name that can be applied to each group. I'll modify the question.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that same page using _class_ as the term. However, when I went to confirm the usage (I am using [Wolfram's MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com) as the authoritative source), I couldn't find the term.