# English word for the comma between three digits

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

[The common number formatting convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) uses a decimal point between the integer part and the fraction, and a comma between every three digits of the number:

```
1000000      -> 1,000,000
12345 + 1/5  -> 12,345.2
```

The `.` is referred to as *Decimal Point*. Is there an English word for the comma separating every three integer digits?

Comment: Commas are used to separate large numbers into groups of three digits. Each group is called a period.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96549/what-is-the-term-for-groups-of-numerals-within-a-large-number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is often called the *thousands separator* or *digit group separator*.

> For ease of reading, numbers with many digits
>   before or after the decimal mark may be divided
>   into groups using a delimiter, with the counting
>   of groups starting from the decimal mark in both directions. This delimiter is usually called a "thousands separator", because the digits are
>   usually in groups of three, that is, thousands. The
>   most general name for this delimiter is "digit
>   group separator", because thousands are not
>   always the relevant group. For example, in various
>   countries (e.g., China, India, and Japan), there have been traditional conventions of grouping by
>   2 or 4 digits.

-[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Some countries use a period for the separator and a comma for the decimal mark.

Comment: In maths lessons, we encouraged the use of spaces rather than commas: 'The problem with the point and the comma as either decimal mark or digit group separator is that, internationally, they have both often been used for both meanings, and their meaning is context-dependent ... which notational system is being used [?]). Therefore the space is recommended in the SI/ISO 31-0 standard, and the International Bureau of Weights and Measures states that "for numbers with many digits the digits may be divided into groups of three by a thin space, in order to facilitate reading."'(Wikipedia op cit)

Comment: In some languages the thousands are separated by a space.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Using spaces makes computer parsing problematic, because `123 456` is ambiguous.

Comment: @AdamMatan There's a thin space [unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space). But you shouldn't be parsing strings to integers when you have already got the integer.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully That's right, but most parsers, and regex splitters, would split the string by any whitespace. This include unicode spaces, newlines, nbsp and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately in the real-world you will find numbers like 123,456.99, 123.456,99, 123 456.99, 123456.99 and 123456,99 so (even if you know the locale) you need to be extra careful with parsing plaintext.

Comment: @Hugo, We can always use the "decide by location" approach. If there's more than one dot or comma, then obviously the last one is the decimal point and the rest the thousands separator isn't it?