# Term for the unit of grouping large numbers?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

I asked this on mathoverflow but I guess it's not so appropriate there so...

In English and probably most (if not all) western languages, we group numbers by powers of 1000. So we have:
ones, tens, hundreds - then
thousands, ten-thousands, hundred-thousands - and so on.

We may take this for granted but it's not universal. In Japanese, for example, we have something like:
ichi (ones), jyuu (tens), hyaku (hundreds), sen (thousands) - then
man (ten-thousands), jyuu-man (hundred-thousands), hyaku-man (millions), sen-man (ten-millions) - then
oku (hundred-millions), jyuu-oku (billions), hyaku-oku (ten-billions), sen-oku (hundred-billions)

So my question is: is there a term for this grouping? Can we say something like, "The [term] in english is 10^3 but the [term] in Japanese is 10^4."

Comment: You may find it relevant to look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96549/what-is-the-term-for-groups-of-numerals-within-a-large-number

Comment: Oh! Thank you! It looks like the term would be "period" although most of the definitions of the term seem to be unaware that there are systems that group numbers in other than 10^3. I will use it in any case.

Comment: My calculator calls it "digit grouping". Many styles don't use a period but a comma to separate, and the idea of the grouping itself isn't called "period" or "comma" – that's just the symbol used as a separator.

Comment: @WeatherVane it seems that it is, in fact, called 'period' but not in the sense of the punctuation mark but rather more like 'periodical'. Fun fact: Japanese use 10^4 as its period but still puts the commas every third digit.